# how to do a count on a grouped by value in Postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of orders and would like to output a list by day of when they were created at of (1) total orders and (2)orders that have a fulfillment_status of 'paid'

```
 id | fulfillment_status | created_at (timestamp witout time zone)
1                           2015-10-17 02:23:14.882131                                            
2      paid                 2015-10-18 02:23:14.882131
3                           2015-10-17 02:23:14.882131
```

so that the output is:

```
date         total_orders total_paid_orders
2015-10-17     1             0
2015-10-18     2             1
```

I get this far:

```
 select count(*) from orders group by created_at ???
```

but ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select created_at::date, 
       count(*) as total_orders,
       count(*) filter (where fulfillment_status = 'paid') as total_paid_orders
from orders
group by created_at::date
order by created_at::date;
```

`created_at::date` converts the timestamp into a date (without a time) and thus groups by day.

`count(*) filter (where fulfillment_status = 'paid')` only counts rows where the condition is true.

Comment: perfect, thx and thx for explanation - very helpful. need to wait a few minutes to accept.